# How to make clear to Clang static analyzer when something's not leaking?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4, clang-static-analyzer

When using Clang static analyzer to analyze my Objective-C code for iOS, I get lots of "potential leaks". Many of the leaks make me wonder why it's erroneous at all. One example that left me wondering in particular was the following:

I have a class-variable of type `NSDictionary`, used for storing some settings. Now when I have a method to change something inside the dictionary:

```
- (void) loadPassengerCompartiments {
    NSMutableArray *paxCompartiments = [self.outputTable objectAtIndex:2];
    NSArray *paxCompSrc = [self.values objectForKey:@"PassengerCompartiments"];

    for(MassPerson *passenger in paxCompSrc) {
=>      [paxCompartiments addObject:[[PaxCompartimentOutputField alloc] initWithPerson:passenger]];
    }
}
```

Clang errs at the in-line allocation and direct association of `PaxCompartimentOutputField`. 
When running this code in instruments it doesn't leak.

Two ways I could come up with to solve this are:

1. use `autorelease`
2. replace the in-line allocation with the following code:

(code)

```
PaxCompartimentOutputField *field = [[PaxCompartimentOutputField alloc] initWithPerson:passenger];
[paxCompartiments addObject:field];
[field release];
```

The first option is obsolete imho (and especially on iOS its use is discouraged)
The second option is pretty bulky - especially when creating an array with more objects (say 10 objects loading default settings).

I don't want to ignore Clang's warnings, as it is an excellent tool for finding bugs & leaks. What is the 'right' way to do this in Objective-C for those cases?

Comment: It is a leak and probably a second leak of paxCompartiments if Instruments doesn't catch anything.

Comment: (rephrase of my last comment): So it's a leak when you alloc an object and pass the pointer as init-value to a NSDictionary instead of a regular variable? The NSDictionary doesn't leak - it's just a class variable referencing multiple objects..

Comment: It doesn't show up as a leak (and it's not) if you keep the dictionary for the life of the application, but its reference count is higher than is correct.  If you tried to release the dictionary and reload it, you would leak the object(s).  - - - This code fix won't "fix" anything here, but when anyone (including a robotic static analyzer) looks at a section of code, they will notice that the memory management is not be handled appropriately.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**That is a leak.**

Since you alloc-init `PaxCompartimentOutputField`, you own it and you must relinquish ownership of it.

You have 3 options (you already mentioned 2 of them):

1) Use a *convenience constructor*, when one is available, or in a custom class, declare one. Convenience constructors return objects **you do not own**, typically by sending an `autorelease` message to the object they return. It would look like this:

```
[paxCompartiments addObject:[PaxCompartimentOutputField paxCompartimentOutputWithPerson:passenger]];
```

2) Use `autorelease`.

```
[paxCompartiments addObject:[[[PaxCompartimentOutputField alloc] initWithPerson:passenger]] autorelease];
```

3) Use a temporary variable.

```
PaxCompartimentOutputField *tempField = [[PaxCompartimentOutputField alloc] initWithPerson:passenger];
[paxCompartiments addObject:tempField];
[tempField release];
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a list of [source annotations](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/annotations.html) that you can use with Clang.

These might help.